# The saturation of Murray von Neumann relation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices, oa.operator-algebras, algebraic-k-theory

**Edit:** According to comment of  Pace Nielsen, I remove question 2 of the previous version:

Let $R$ be a unital ring. We define  Murray Von Neumann  relation $M$ on $R$ as follows:

We say $a M b$ iff $a=xy,\;b=yx$ for some $x,y\in R$. (This is inspired by the usual Murray Von Neumann equivalent relation in K theory, which is defined on the set of idempotents of  a  ring). The relation $M$ is a reflexive  and symmetric relation but is not a transitive relation. So we consider its  saturation. The saturation of this relation is an equivalent  relation denoted by $\simeq$. In fact we say $a\simeq b$ if there are $p_{i}\in R\;$  with $p_{0} M p_{1},\;\;\;p_{1}  M p_{2},\ldots p_{n-1} M p_{n}$  where $p_{0}=a,\;p_{n}=b$.

Put $R=M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. One can show that the equivalent class containing $0$ is $$[0]=\{A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})\mid A^{n}=0\}$$

(In fact one can prove the following: If $A\in B(H)$ satisfy $A^{k}=0$ then there are $X,Y\in B(H)$  with $A=XY$  and $(YX)^{k-1}=0$. Here $B(H)$ is the space of bounded operators on a  Hilbert space. The same is true by replacing $B(H)$   with an  arbitrary  Von Neumann  algebra. The  same  also is true   without any topological consideration, that is by replacing $B(H)$  with $L(V)$, the space of linear endomorphisms of  a vector space $V$.)

So for  $R=M_{n}(\mathbb{C}),\;\;[0]$  is  an algebraic variety,i.e: the variety of nilpotent  matrices  $A^{n}=0$

> 1.Is every equivalent class  of  $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ an  algebraic variety?(the zero set of  polynomials on $M_{n}(\mathbb{C}) \simeq \mathbb{C}^{n^{2}}$ or the zero set of  polynomials in the form $f(A)=0$ where $f\in \mathbb{C}[x]$?What is the precise description of equivalent classes?
>
> 2. Assume that  $A$ is  a  $C^{*}$  algebra  and $a\in A$  satisfies $a^{k}=0$  for  some  $k>1$. Are there two elements $x,y \in A$  with $a=xy$  and $(yx)^{k-1}=0$?

**Note:**Inspired by methods from K theory, I tried to construct a functor $NK$ based on the constructions above. please see  [A functor on the category of rings, algebras or compact Hausdorff topological space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232293/a-functor-on-the-category-of-rings-algebras-or-compact-hausdorff-topological-s)

Perhaps, it would be interesting to ask "Is there a kind of periodicity property for this functor?"

Comment: For matrices over the complexes, $XY = A$ and $YX = B$ implies that their nonzero Jordan normal forms are the same (that is, discard the nilpotent parts of their JNFs); it follows that the equivalence relation generated by the relation is exactly equality of JNF away from zero (this is just a special case of a similar, but more complicated result when we have integer matrices).

Comment: @DavidHandelman  Thank you for your  comment. Can you give  a  reference for that result?

Comment: @PaceNielsen  Thanks for your  comment.  The saturation is the same definition which I wrote in the post. I learned it from  a paper by J. Petre in his paper on characterization of linear operator decreasing the support(A paper in French). Regarding my second question, you are right, it was a typo. i revise it.

Comment: $\le$ is strange notation for a relation that's symmetric. Anyway, note that your definition makes no use of the additive structure, so you might as well state it for monoids. In that setting you are asking for the (zeroth) Hochschild homology of a monoid. I don't know if this has been studied much for monoids as opposed to categories. For rings it's more natural to quotient by the subspace spanned by commutators, which gets you the usual zeroth Hochschild homology.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  Thank you. i revise the notation.

Comment: @PaceNielsen  Yes. thanks. so it seems that I need to add more assumption for example the  simolicity of R.

Comment: Correction: Simplicity of R.

Comment: It has been pointed out at meta (http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2749/how-to-discourage-excessive-self-edits) that this post has undergone numerous recent edits, some of them quite minor. As you know, each edit bumps the post to the front page and pushes other questions off the front page, which can be an annoyance to others. Let's please bring the editing to a close so that users have a stable question to look at.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thank you for your comment. But is not possible the following software change in MO: Consideration of two types of edites: minor  and major. 
For minor edit, the edited post would not appear at the first page.(front page)


This enable the asker to revise his/her question(with choosing minor edit).

Comment: Is this change  really difficult ?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: That's a  major change to the core system; you would have to propose it in meta.stackoverflow; moderators in MO don't really have the power to make such a change. So yes, such a change would be "really difficult". Moreover, lots of people seem to be perfectly able to NOT edit their questions multiple times for minor issues, so would a minor change in your behavior towards the norm be really difficult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to the second question, yes this is true. Say $x^k=0$.   Let $x=v|x|$ be the polar decomposition of $x$ in $A^{**}$ (the bidual of $A$). Let $a=v|x|^{\frac 1 2}$ and $b=|x|^{\frac 1 2}$. Then clearly $x=ab$.
Both $a$ and $b$ belong to $A$. In $b$'s case, by functional calculus. It is a well-known property of polar decompositions that $v|x|^{\frac 1 2}$ is also in $A$. To see this, write $p_n(|x|)\to |x|^{\frac 1 2}$, where each $p_n$ is a polynomial such that $p_n(0)=0$. Then $vp_n(|x|)\to v|x|^{\frac 1 2}$ in norm and $vp_n(|x|)\in A$ for all $n$ because we can factor out $|x|$ from $p_n(|x|)$.

Now consider $ba=|x|^{\frac 1 2}v|x|^{\frac 1 2}$ (the Aluthge transform of $x$). Then
    $$
(ba)^{k-1}(ba)^*=
(|x|^{\frac 1 2}v|x|^{\frac 1 2}\cdots |x|^{\frac 1 2}v|x|^{\frac 1 2})\cdot 
|x|^{\frac 1 2}v^*|x|^{\frac 1 2}= 
|x|^{\frac 1 2}x^{k-1} v^*|x|^{\frac 1 2}=0,
 $$ 
    where we have used that $|x|^{\frac 1 2}x^{k-1}=0$ (since  $|x|^{\frac 1 2}\in C^*(x^*x)$ and $(x^*x)x^{k-1}=0$). It follows that $(ba)^{k-1}((ba)^{k-1})^*=0$ which implies that $(ba)^{k-1}=0$.

Comment: is the polar  decomposition legal in the idealizer of $A$ in $A^{**}$?If i am not mistaken, it is necessary in your argument.

Comment: I've expanded the arguments to make the answer more clear.

Comment: I  really thank you very much for your very interesting  and  elegance answer.Is there a particular reason that you consider the polar decomposition in the bidual of A, instead of some $B(H)$  where $B(H)$ faithfully contains$A$?