# A functor on the category of rings, algebras or compact Hausdorff topological space

Tags: gn.general-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras

Assume that $R$ is  a unital ring or  a  complex or real   (Banach or  $C^{*}$) algebra.

We  define  a relation $M$  on $R$ as follows: $$a\;M  b \;\;\;  \text{iff}\;\; a=xy,\;b=yx \;\; \text{for  some}\;\; x,y\in R$$  It is  a reflexive and symmetric (but  not transitive )  relation. We  define an equivalent relation $\simeq$ on $R$ as  follows:

$a\simeq b$ if there are $p_{i}\in R,\;i=0,1,\ldots,n$  with $$\begin{cases}a=p_{0},\;\; b=p_{n},&\\ p_{i} \; M\; p_{i+1}\end{cases}$$

The space of **nilpotent** elements of $R$, denoted by $N(R)$, is  a  saturated subset of $R$, with respect to this equivalent relation,  while the space of idempotent elements is not necessarily a saturated subset.

Notation: $M_{n}(R)$ is the space of $n\times n$  matrices with entries in $R$.

The   natural  mapping $M_{n}(R) \to  M_{n+1} (R)$ with $A \mapsto A\oplus 0$ sends  nilpotent elements to   nilpotent elements.  Moreover the above equivalent relation is  preserved under this map.

We  consider $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} N(M_{n}(R))$, the union of  all  nilpotent  matrices of all size. The equivalent relation  $\simeq$ has a natural extension to the later space: $A\simeq  B$ if there are natural numbers  $k,p$  such that $A\oplus 0_{k} \simeq B\oplus  0_{p}$. The later are  the zero matrices of  size $k,p$, respectively.

This enable us to equip $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} N(M_{n}(R))/\simeq$  to  an Abelian semi group structure, via the usual matrix-sum.(Note that for two  nilpotent  elements  $a,b$  with $ab=ba=0$,  $a+b$ is  again  a  nilpotent element. On the other hand every two elements of the above  quotient space have two representation $A,B$  with $AB=BA=0$). Because,   for every $a\in R$  we  have $\begin{pmatrix} a&0\\0&0  \end{pmatrix} \simeq \begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&a \end{pmatrix}$.

> The Grothendick group of this  semi group  is  denoted  by $NK(R)$.

**Questions:**

> What is  an example of  a $C^{*}$ algebra  $A$ for which $NK(A)$  is a  non trivial group? Is there  a  commutative  $C^{*}$  algebra $A$ with  nontrivial $NK(A)$.

**Note 1** The mapping $A\mapsto  NK(A)$ is  realy  a functor on the category of  rings or  algebra. according to Gelfand  Naimark duality this could  be  counted  as  a  functor on the category of  compact  Hausdorff topological  space

**Note 2:** This  post  is  inspired by the construction in algebraic K theory and the following two posts

[The saturation of Murray von Neumann relation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231328/the-saturation-of-murray-von-neumann-relation)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661660/the-reduction-of-nilpotency-order-of-nilpotent-elements-of-c-algebras

Comment: What does this construction give for $R={\mathbb C}$?

Comment: @YemonChoi  This  construction  for $\mathbb{C}$ gives the trivial group(As I explained here:.http://mathoverflow.net/questions/231328/the-saturation-of-murray-von-neumann-relation)

Comment: Let $A,B \in \cup_n M_n(R)$ be a pair of nilpotent matrices such that $AB = BA = 0$ and let $A',B' \in \cup_n M_n(R)$ be another pair of nilpotent matrices over such that $A'B' = B'A' = 0$. If $A \simeq A'$ and $B \simeq B'$, is there any reason to think that $A+B \simeq A'+B'$? This seems like a prerequisite result one would need in order to show that the desired semi-group structure on $\cup_n M_n(R)/\simeq$ is well-defined.

Comment: @YonatanHarpaz  Thank you for your attention to my question. I confess that I did not pay attention to this prerequisit,. The nilpotent version of proposition 4.2.4 of page 26 of  Blackadar book on K theory. The reason that i did not pay attention:I was saying myself $a\simeq..a'$ and $b\simeq b'$ imply that $\begin{pmatrix} a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix} \simeq \begin{pmatrix}a'&0\\0&b'\end {pmatrix}$,. So according to your comment, my construction collaps if that prerequisite can not be proved.

Comment: @YonatanHarpaz   Of course we can not give  a counter example in matrix algebra or operator algebra or Von Neumann algebras, because all nilpotent  elements  are equivalent to each other. But what about other algebras? Thanks again for your very interesting comment.